# Does a run score if the batter is tagged for the 3rd out before he reaches first?

Tags: baseball

There is a runner on third with two out. Batter hits a slow roller to first base. First baseman charges and picks up the ball. Runner from third crosses home. First baseman tags the runner running from home to first, does the run count ?

Comment: It seems relevant here to mention the fourth out rule, as described here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_out

In essence, if a runner scores prior to a third out which is not a force out, a force out can be subsequently made as a fourth out.  The fourth out then supercedes the third out and the run is nullified.

Answer (score 13):

The run does not count. According to [MLB rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/official_info/official_rules/start_end_4.jsp):

> 4.09 HOW A TEAM SCORES.
>
> (a) One run shall be scored each time a runner legally advances to and touches first,
> second, third and home base before three men are put out to end the inning.
> **EXCEPTION: A run is not scored if the runner advances to home base during a
> play in which the third out is made (1) by the batter-runner before he touches first
> base;** (2) by any runner being forced out; or (3) by a preceding runner who is
> declared out because he failed to touch one of the bases.

Since the batter-runner does not make it to first base safely, the run does not count. Similar to a force out.