# If a forced runner is tagged for the 3rd out, do any runs count?

Tags: rules, baseball

Bases loaded with 2 outs. Ball is hit to shortstop. SS tags runner attempting to advance to 3rd. Does the run count from 3rd base

Comment: This is not a duplicate, just closely related.  This question asks about what happens if a runner other than the batter is tagged out.  As the answer to this question shows, this is not the same situation as tagging out the batter before he reaches first base.

Comment: a better duplicate would be https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/does-a-run-scored-on-a-tag-out-on-a-forced-runner

Comment: Actually, [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/21264/bases-loaded-scoring-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a much more direct and definitive duplicate. I'm surprised this very scenario has been asked about (at least) three times on this site.

Comment: I've flipped the duplicate here, it now seems to me this does directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The run does not count. Rule 4.09 of the [MLB rule book](http://mlb.mlb.com/documents/0/8/0/268272080/2018_Official_Baseball_Rules.pdf) states:

> 4.09 HOW A TEAM SCORES.
>
> (a) One run shall be scored each time a runner legally advances to and touches first,
> second, third and home base before three men are put out to end the inning.
> **EXCEPTION: A run is not scored if the runner advances to home base during a
> play in which the third out is made** (1) by the batter-runner before he touches first
> base; **(2) by any runner being forced out;** or (3) by a preceding runner who is
> declared out because he failed to touch one of the bases.

The runner attempting to advance to third is forced out for the third out. As a result, the run is not scored.

Comment: However, because this was a tag play and *not* a force play, realize that in the unlikely -- but possible -- scenario where the runner from third has touched home plate *before* the tag is made the run *would* count.

Comment: @jimmym715 It was my understanding that a tag on a forced runner is a force out: https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/5771. Please advise.

Comment: @jimmym715 why do you describe this as a tag play?  It appears to be the perfect example of a force play. Force is on until/unless the runner reaches the next base or a trailing runner is put out.

Comment: @BowlOfRed because the OP specified a tag by the SS between 2nd and 3rd as opposed to a force out at 3rd

Comment: Tagging a runner doesn't mean that it's not a "force play".  https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/does-a-run-scored-on-a-tag-out-on-a-forced-runner

Comment: @jimmym715 Here's a [rule reference](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/16448) that essentially states that a tag on a forced runner is a force out.